# Even distribution of PHP arrays across columns

Tags: php

So, I want to distribute evenly lists across 3 columns. The lists cannot be broken up or reordered.

At the moment, I have 5 lists each containing respectively 4, 4, 6, 3 and 3 items.

My initial approach was:

```
$lists = [4,4,6,3,3];
$columns = 3;
$total_links = 20;
$items_per_column = ceil($total_links/$columns);
$current_column = 1;
$counter = 0;
$lists_by_column = [];
foreach ($lists as $total_items) {
    $counter += $total_items;
    $lists_by_column[$current_column][] = $total_items;
    if ($counter > $current_column*$links_per_column) {
        $current_column++;
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
[
    [4],
    [4,6],
    [3,3]
]
```

But, I want it to look like this:

```
[
    [4,4],
    [6],
    [3,3]
]
```

I want to always have the least possible variation in length between the columns.

Other examples of expected results:

`[6,4,4,6]` => `[[6], [4,4], [6]]`

`[4,4,4,4,6]` => `[[4,4], [4,4], [6]]`

`[10,4,4,3,5]` => `[[10], [4,4], [3,5]]`

`[2,2,4,6,4,3,3,3]` => `[[2,2,4], [6,4], [3,3,3]]`

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. What do you mean by `I want the first column to contain the first 2 lists, the second, the third list and the last must contain the last 2 lists.` Another thing is why your expected output of `10, 4, 4, 3, 5` is different than `4, 4, 4, 4, 6`?

Comment: I did find those requirements very unclear... it doesn't have a clear pattern, and that question sounds like an XY problem. What are you *really* trying to do with that distribution? There may be a better solution.

Comment: This will be used to render a nested menu. The numbers are the total of links inside one menu item. The trick here is that I don't want to break any menu item, but I want to distribute them evenly across 3 columns.

Comment: Yeah but in your last example, [3,5] doesn't seem evenly distribuited.

Comment: It is because if you add up the totals for each column, it results in `[10,8,8]` which is the best you can do to have 3 columns with the closest number of links in each column given the restriction of not being able to break the inital lists.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly what you need to do is loop over the number of columns within your foreach(). That will distribute them for you.

```
$numrows = ceil(count($lists) / $columns);
$thisrow = 1;
foreach ($lists as $total_items) {
    if($thisrow < $numrows){
        for($i = 1; $i <= $columns; $i++){
            $lists_by_column[$i][] = $total_items;
        }
    }else{
        //this is the last row
        //find out how many columns need to fit.
        //1 column is easy, it goes in the first column
        //2 columns is when you'll need to skip the middle one
        //3 columns is easy because it's full
    }
    $thisrow++;
}
```

This will be an even distribution, from left to right. But you actually want a modified even distribution that will look symmetrical to the eye. So within the foreach loop, you'll need to keep track of 1.) if you're on the last row of three, and 2.) if there are 2 remainders, to have it skip col2 and push to col3 instead.  You'll need to set that up to be able to play around with it,...but you're just a couple of logic gates away from the land of milk and honey.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `if you're on the last row of three`

Comment: If your array had 23 keys and you know you want 3 columns. You know you're going to need 8 rows to hold them all...ceil(23 / 3).  So for the first 7 rows,...everything is normal and full and being distributed evenly. You don't need to do anything.

On the last row, you'll need to introduce the logic to handle which column goes where.  I'll amplify my example a bit, so you can see the flow.

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer and see if there is anything that could be made better? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33174771/1413272 Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up using this code:

```
$lists = [4,4,6,3,3];
$columns = 3;
$total_links = 20;
$items_per_column = ceil($total_links/$columns);
$current_column = 1;
$lists_by_column = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($lists); $i++) {
    $total = $lists[$i];
    $lists_by_column[$current_column][] = $lists[$i];

    //Loop until reaching the end of the column
    while ($total < $items_per_column && $i+1 < count($lists)) {
        if ($total + $lists[$i+1] > $items_per_column) {
            break;
        }
        $i++;
        $total += $lists[$i];
        $lists_by_column[$current_column][] = $lists[$i];
    }

    //When exiting the loop the last time we need another break
    if (!isset($lists[$i+1])) {break;}

    //If the last item goes onto the next column
    if (abs($total - $items_per_column) < abs($total + $lists[$i+1] - $items_per_column)) {
        $current_column++;
    //If the last item goes onto the current column
    } else if ($total + $lists[$i+1] > $items_per_column) {
        $i++;
        $lists_by_column[$current_column][] = $lists[$i];
        $current_column++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple style things could make it a bit easier to read.
1.) You could hardcode $columns if that never changes
2.) if (!isset($lists[$i+1])) {break;}  doesn't need the braces around break; And there's a couple of spots where you could use the shorthand if statement.
3.) if count($lists) is the same as $total_links you could do that count once at the top.